# How to find Git commits not in any branch?

Tags: git, repository, commit

In the repository I'm currently working there are a bunch of commits whose branches were removed without being merged, but because tags were created pointing to the commits, these will live on forever.

How can I list these tags to remove them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **bash script** on linux to find commits that are not in any branch, you run  script in your Git repository.

This script will iterate through all commits not in any branch and remove tags associated with them.

if you will show you a list of commits that are not part of any local or remote branch use it:

**git log --all --not --branches='*' --remotes='*' --format="%H"**

```
#!/bin/bash

for commit_id in $(git log --all --not --branches=* --format="%H")
do
    for tag in $(git tag --contains $commit_id)
    do
        echo "Removing tag: $tag"
        git tag -d $tag
    done
done
```

Comment: `git log --all --not --branches=*` returns all commits.

Comment: This command display the commit history of local branches that have commits not present in the remote tracking branches of the "origin" remote repository. i tested my code first, It helps in understanding the divergence between local and remote branches. then define your question better.

Comment: I think the original question is pretty simple; what I meant to say with my previous comment is that the command `git log --all --not --branches=*` lists commits from existing branches, not just unreachable ones.